# CustomAuthorizationPolicy.Evaluate() method never fires in wcf webhttpbinding

Tags: c#, wcf, authorization, restful-architecture

I create a wcf service as you can see :

```
[OperationContract]
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Admin")]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/Data/{data}")]

string GetData(string data);
```

So I create a custom authorize  as you can see :

```
public class AuthorizationPolicy : IAuthorizationPolicy
{
    string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public string Id
    {
        get { return this.id; }
    }

    public System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimSet Issuer
    {
        get { return System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimSet.System; }
    }

    // this method gets called after the authentication stage
    public bool Evaluate(EvaluationContext evaluationContext, ref object state)
    {
        // get the authenticated client identity
        IIdentity client = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;

        // set the custom principal
        evaluationContext.Properties["Principal"] = new CustomPrincipal(client);

        return true;
    }
}

public class CustomPrincipal : IPrincipal
{
    private IIdentity _identity;
    public IIdentity Identity
    {
        get
        {
            return _identity;
        }
    }

    public CustomPrincipal(IIdentity identity)
    {
        _identity = identity;
    }

    public bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        //my code 
        return true;

       // return Roles.IsUserInRole(role);
    }
}
```

And authentication:

```
  public class RestAuthorizationManager: ServiceAuthorizationManager
    {
        protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
        {
            //Extract the Authorization header, and parse out the credentials converting the Base64 string:  
            var authHeader = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["Authorization"];
            if ((authHeader != null) && (authHeader != string.Empty))
            {
                var svcCredentials = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII
                    .GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authHeader.Substring(6)))
                    .Split(':');
                var user = new
                {
                    Name = svcCredentials[0],
                    Password = svcCredentials[1]
                };
                if ((user.Name == "1" && user.Password == "1"))
                {
                    //here i get the role of my user from the database
                    // return Admin role 
                    //User is authrized and originating call will proceed  
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //not authorized  
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //No authorization header was provided, so challenge the client to provide before proceeding:  
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"MyWCFService\"");
                //Throw an exception with the associated HTTP status code equivalent to HTTP status 401  
                throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            }
        }
    }
```

So I create and https hosting in my IIS and I upload the service, my authentication class is working but my authorize doesn't .why?I define my authentication in my web config as you can see.But I don't know how can I define my authorize in my web config.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<client />

<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding>
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">

      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceAuthorization
        serviceAuthorizationManagerType  
    ="wcfrestauth.RestAuthorizationManager, wcfrestauth"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttpServiceBehavior">
      <!-- Important this is the behavior that makes a normal WCF service to REST based service-->
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="wcfrestauth.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/WCFRestAuthentication/api/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="wcfrestauth.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpServiceBehavior" />
  </service>
</services>

<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https"/>

</protocolMapping>

<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

I mean when I call my service in client .the service doesn't check the authorize function.i should define my custom authorize class inside the webconfig but i don't know how ?

```
public bool IsInRole(string role)
{
    //my code 
    return true;

    // return Roles.IsUserInRole(role);
}
```

Comment: I really need your help

Answer (score 1):

You might need to set `serviceCredentials` in your `web config` file:

```
<serviceCredentials type="YourString">
     <YourTagsHere>
     </YourTagsHere>
</serviceCredentials>
```

Here's a link to more information about `serviceCredentials`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/servicecredentials

Comment: Thank you dear friend but i think i can't use it in my binding am i right ?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify your custom AuthorizationPolicy within the `<serviceAuthorization>` tags, e.g.:

```
<serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType=
        "wcfrestauth.RestAuthorizationManager, wcfrestauth">
  <authorizationPolicies>         
    <add policyType="wcfrestauth.AuthorizationPolicy, wcfrestauth"  
  </authorizationPolicies> 
</serviceAuthorization>
```

In the WCF docs there is a good example for Implementing a [Custom Authorization Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-create-a-custom-authorization-policy) for a WCF service.

Be careful, though, when overriding the CheckAccess method of the abstract AuthorizationManager base class. The method of the base class calls the `GetAuthorizationPolicies` method internally to retrieve a collection of all IAuthorizationPolicy objects present (see also [this blog article](https://blog.pedrofelix.org/2008/08/06/the-serviceauthorizationmanager-class-in-wcf/) - Edit: Link is dead but article is in the [Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20201020024910/https://blog.pedrofelix.org/2008/08/06/the-serviceauthorizationmanager-class-in-wcf/)).

If you override CheckAcces and do not invoke the method of the parent class, not any Evaluate method of the IAuthorizationPolicy objects will be called.