# custom authorization and authentication in wcf webhttpbindig

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, authorization, webhttpbinding

I create a simple wcf service with webhttpbinding as you can see :

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/Data/{data}")]
    string GetData(string data);
```

and the implementation :

```
   public string GetData(string value)
        {

                return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);

        }
```

I want to create a custom authorization and authentication about 2 weeks but i can't.i googled a lot ,but i can find authentication for wshttpbinding not webhttpbinding .

My recent question that describe main problem :

[My authorize custom function in wcf doesn't execute .Should i define it in webconfig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45767892/my-authorize-custom-function-in-wcf-doesnt-execute-should-i-define-it-in-webco)

[My CustomAuthorizationPolicy.Evaluate() method never fires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45770217/my-customauthorizationpolicy-evaluate-method-never-fires)

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the [ServiceAuthorizationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceauthorizationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) to provide authorization to your WCF service with webhttpbinding.

Your code could look similar to this:

```
public class CustomAuthorizationManager : ServiceAuthorizationManager
{
    protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        try
        {
            ServiceSecurityContext securityContext = operationContext.ServiceSecurityContext;
            WindowsIdentity callingIdentity = securityContext.WindowsIdentity;

            WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(callingIdentity);
            return principal.IsInRole("Administrators");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then register your custom ServiceAuthorizationManager in the web.config file:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
    <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
    <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="YourNamespace.CustomAuthorizationManager, YourAssemblyName"/>
  </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

Comment: Thank you ,But how can i check the role .I mean how can i check if the user role is correct execute the operation ?

Comment: `principal.IsInRole("Administrators");`

Comment: when i call the service IsInRole returns false

Comment: I want to check the operation role with my database role ,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45794914/custom-authorize-and-authentication-using-operationcontext-in-wcf